# ajax call to web-api worked for GET but not working for POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

my javascript function:

```
function CheckLogin() {
        var user = { "UserName": $('#UN').val(), "Password": $('#P').val() };
       $.ajax({

            url: 'http://localhost/MvcRazorClient/api/HomeApi/SignIn',
            type: 'POST',
            data: user,
            async: false,
            contentType:'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == true)
                {

                    alert('true');

                }
                else{
                    alert('false');
                }


                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');

                    }
                });
            }
```

my web-api method:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SignIn(string UserName, string Password)
{
return true;
}
```

i was able to pass data i.e user to the web-api when i used GET request but i am not able to pass when POST is used. 
please help.

Comment: what response do you get?

Comment: error pop up. web-api method didnt get hit. for GET i am getting true @Ryan Dansie

Comment: when you send the post what you get? 404 error?

Comment: how can i see what error i m getting? @Zach dev, since i kept an alert pop up ,msg is popping out

Comment: The error pop up is your javascript alert. What http response do you get when doing the "POST" request? status code, response body etc. If your using chrome, you can inspect the request/response in the developer tools. See the "Network" tab, look for the request url and click on it to see the details

Comment: you must use any kind of proxy, the fast way is with developer tools from google chrome browser.

Comment: 500 (internal servaer error) @ Ryan Dansie @Zach dev

Comment: If you look at the response body it will contain more details about the error

Comment: SignIn:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not definedSignIn:59 (anonymous function) @ Ryan Dansie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CheckLogin() {
        var user = { "UserName": $('#UN').val(), "Password": $('#P').val() };
        user = JSON.stringify(user);//changes made here
       $.ajax({

            url: 'http://localhost/MvcRazorClient/api/HomeApi/SignIn',
            type: 'POST',
            data: user,
            async: false,
            contentType:'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == true)
                {

                    alert('true');

                }
                else{
                    alert('false');
                }


                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');

                    }
                });
            }
```

my web-api method:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SignIn(HttpRequestMessage req)//changes made here
{
var data = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;// to extract data
      JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a c# object like:

```
public class User
{
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

and then update your controller to take in a User instead of the two strings, like

```
[HttpPost] 
public bool SignIn(User user) 
{ 
  return true; 
}
```

you might also have to update your javascript object since the ajax call is telling the server to expect a json object, you might need to your user object creation line to

```
var user = { "userName": $('#UN').val(), "password": $('#P').val() };
```

Comment: user was null or the values UserName and Password weren't populated? What does the call look like in the network tab of your browser? Are you getting any errors in the browser?

Comment: It has been my experience with WebApi that since in javascript you are passing an object, the WebApi serializer treats what comes in as an object and it looks for properties on the object(in this case UserName and Password) to serialize the values that are passed to the method to.

Comment: in the first line, user was defined

Comment: @Zachdev This answer is pretty good, you need to realise that what you send to the server in a Post request is sent through the body and not as a query string like Get requests do.

Comment: Yes I know that as well, not sure how that would change my answer, but thanks for clarifying for others.